# Is there a way to read two files at the same time in python? (with the same loop?)

Tags: python

I am trying to read 2 files at the same time right now, but I get a "too many values to unpack error". Here is what I have:

```
for each_f, each_g in f, g :
    line_f = each_f.split()
    line_g = each_g.split()
```

I am a little new to python but I assumed I would be able to do this. If this is impossible, is there an equivalent method? (The two files I am reading are very large)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import itertools

# ...

for each_f, each_g in itertools.izip(f, g):
    # ...
```

Comment: `import itertools` could be needed.

Comment: it might not be obvious to OP, hence the comment.

Comment: @shahkalpesh ok, I still believe that it's really obvious, but I'll add it to my answer just in case…

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I am a beginner in python too. Can the same thing be achieved without using itertools?

Comment: @shahkalpesh Yes, but it requires you to manually read from each of the files in a while loop, as a for loop can iterate over only one iterator at a time. `izip` merges the two iterators into one so that the for loop can operate on it.

Comment: @kirelagin: In fact, itertools could just be a nice thing. Just thought of checking if using a tuple, this can be done?

Comment: @shahkalpesh No, it can't be done using a tuple. You need a generator wrapping a pair of generators and getting `next` from both of them at the same time. You can iterate it manually, though.

Comment: As @chepner noted in his answer `izip` breaks out as soon as the shorted of the two files ends. Something to keep in mind.

Comment: There is `iziplongest` as well, which will supply `None` (or a user-specified value) for the shorter iterator until the longer is exhausted as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a context manager, i.e. the with statement to read two files at the same time:

```
with open('file1', 'r') as a, open('file2', 'r') as b:  
    do_something_with_a_and_b
```

Comment: I think this shouldn't be downvoted like this; this is a simple answer to the question title, which then happens to not coincide with the real problem. It's the title that should be fixed to something like `too many values to unpack in for loop`

Answer (score 1):

Without using `itertools`:

```
while True:
    try:
        f_line = next(f)
        g_line = next(f)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

This breaks out of the loop as soon as the shorter of the two files is exhausted, as `izip` does as well.

But really, `itertools` is the superior solution.